# GROUP_CONCAT && left outer join on 1 table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-concat

I've got 1 table with Menu labels in it.I need with a query to get Parent label and UnderMenu label.when i execute this:

```
  SELECT es.Label MenuLabel, m.Label UnderLabel 
  FROM books_menu es
  LEFT JOIN books_menu m ON es.ID = m.MenuParentID 
  WHERE es.ParentID =1 
  AND m.Type='under'
  AND es.Type='main' 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

everything is OK but MenuLabel show on every record.Something like this:

```
  MenuLabel    UnderLabel
  Home         1
  Home         2
  Home         3
  Contacts     4
```

When i execute :

```
  SELECT es.Label MenuLabel, GROUP_CONCAT(m.Label) AS UnderLabel 
  FROM books_menu es
  LEFT JOIN books_menu m ON es.ID = m.MenuParentID 
  WHERE es.ParentID =1 
  AND m.Type='under'
  AND es.Type='main' 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

i get:

```
      MenuLabel    UnderLabel
       Home         1,2,3,4
```

How can i get this:

```
   MenuLabel    UnderLabel
   Home         1,2,3
   Contacts     4
```

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT es.Label MenuLabel, GROUP_CONCAT(m.Label) AS UnderLabel 
FROM books_menu es
LEFT JOIN books_menu m ON es.ID = m.MenuParentID 
WHERE es.ParentID =1 
      AND m.Type='under'
      AND es.Type='main' 
GROUP BY MenuLabel    
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```